# PHP ssh2_connect to remote passwordless server

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I have setup SSH passwordless login between local client and remote server.

Local client has private key, remote server added with local client's public key.

local client is able to SSH/SFTP to remote server without password -> sftp remoteusr@server

```
---on local client machine---
private key location -> /home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa (owner:group = localusr:localusr)
public key path -> /home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (owner:group = localusr:localusr)

---on remote server---
added client public key to /home/remoteusr/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I was not able to establish SFTP connection using PHP from local client

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($server, $port, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn, 'remoteusr', '/home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa')) {
    echo "Public Key Authentication Successful";
} else {
    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}
```

I encountered this error

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for 
remoteusr using public key: Unable to open public key file in 
xxx.php on line 29
```

**SOLUTION**:

This is due to permission issue, i think somehow apache server does not have permission to read the keys. Able to make it work by copying private and public key from

```
/home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/localusr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

To

```
/var/www/project/id_rsa
/var/www/project/id_rsa.pub
and chmod 700
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php

Comment: the location of public and private key is it to use the path on Server B or Server A? I tried adding Server A private key and public key path ,but encountered this error  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for sftp_comet_dev using public key: Unable to open public key file

Comment: "Unable to open public key file" --- explains the problem clearly enough I suppose

Comment: unfortunately the paths are all correct. i tried with the path on Server A, didnt work. I tried copy private and public keys into Server B and point to Server B's path, didnt work either

Comment: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn, $user, '/ServerA/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/ServerA/.ssh/id_rsa')   and ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn, $user, '/ServerB/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/ServerB/.ssh/id_rsa')   both didnt work

Comment: First, avoid calling a *client* machine (client from the perspective of your question) a *server*. It's so confusing! So instead of *"Server A"* and *"Server B"*, say *"client"* and *"server"* or *"local"* and *"remote"*. It will help even you, not to get confused.

Comment: *"both didnt work"* - means what? What exact error message/problem did you get for those specific statements? Add all information into your question. Do not post them in comments.

Comment: `/ServerA/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` I hardly believe this path exists on your server.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thanks for your suggestion, i've added all information in the post.

Comment: How do you run the PHP? Is it a web page? Or a standalone script?

Comment: running on apache web server

Comment: Show `ls -la /home/localusr/.ssh` and `ls -ld /home/localusr`

Comment: solved, permission issue, thanks for your help

Comment: Never ever give permissions to your private key to every one! Make a copy of the key in a folder that can be accessed by your web server.

Comment: i copy the keys to /var/www folder which is accessible by httpd. and change the permission to 754, it this better ?

Comment: No. The key may not be readable by anyone, except for the user that uses the key. Change the ownership to httpd account and set permissions to 700.